# PyCharm fails to install module packages. Why?

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm 2017.2 installed on Windows 7.

I guess I'm having some issue with installation of packages- and I can't get to the root of it.
Install via settings, project interpeter - and got this message ( for csv module - as an example, which I know it should be a part of internal packages):

> Collecting csv
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for csv

Comment: CSV is a built-in part of the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe- it was an example since basic fucntion csv.write failed ( while script  on IDLE is OK ). same problem from module `gpiozero` from controling GPIO